# Proper way to pass a big object into a directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a big data structure, that I want to display using Angular directives.

```
{
  name: 'structure',
  groups: [{
    name: 'one group',
    entries: [{
      name: 'a',
      type: 'a'
    }, {
      name: 'b',
      type: 'a'
    }]         
  }, {
    name: 'other group',
    entries: [{
      name: 'c',
      type: 'b'
    }, {
      name: 'd',
      type: 'a'
    }]
  }]
}
```

Currently, my directive includes the entire object as a value:

```
<!-- main.html -->
<div ng-repeat="group in groups">
  <my-group group-data="{{group}}"></my-group>
</div>

<!-- group.html -->
<div ng-repeat="entry in group.entries>
  <my-entry entry-data="{{entry}}"></my-entry>
</div>

<!-- entry.html -->
<div ng-if="entry.type === 'a'>{{entry.name}}</div>
```

```
// directives.js
angular.module('my-module')
  .directive('my-group', function() {
     return {
       templateUrl:'group.html',
       link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
         scope.$watch(attributes.groupData, function(value) {
           scope.group = value;
         });
       }
     });
     // similar for my-entry
```

This works, as long as the structure doesn't change. The problem is, when the value of some entry in `groups` in the scope changes, the change is propagated and visible in `main.html`, but not in `group.html` or `entry.html`. Also, the entire object is included in the DOM, which feels wrong.

I've tried using a `scope: {group: '='}` on my directive, but then I don't get the value through at all. I've tried using `attributes.$observe('group', function (value) { /* same impl */ })` instead of `scope.$watch`, but that seems to receive the object as a string, so I can't access individual properties without parsing it (which feels even more wrong).

How do I pass an object tree into a directive, and watch it for changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using $watch incorrectly. Parameter for $watch must be name of a variable inside scope, or function that returns some value. Also there is no need to watch this params manually better use directive scope:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="my-module" data-ng-controller="myController">
    <div ng-repeat="group in groups">
        <my-group group-data="group"></my-group>
    </div>
    <button type="button" ng-click="changeEntryName()">Change</button>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('my-module', [])
            .controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
                $scope.groups = [{
                    name: 'one group',
                    entries: [{
                        name: 'a',
                        type: 'a'
                    }, {
                        name: 'b',
                        type: 'a'
                    }]
                }, {
                    name: 'other group',
                    entries: [{
                        name: 'c',
                        type: 'b'
                    }, {
                        name: 'd',
                        type: 'a'
                    }]
                }];

                $scope.changeEntryName = function() {
                    $scope.groups[0].entries[0].name = 'Kowabunga!';
                };
            }])
            .directive('myGroup', function() {
                return {
                    templateUrl:'group.html',
                    scope: {
                        group: '=groupData'
                    }
                }
            })
            .directive('myEntry', function() {
                return {
                    templateUrl:'entry.html',
                    scope: {
                        entry: '=entryData'
                    }
                }
            });
    </script>
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="group.html">
        <div ng-repeat="entry in group.entries">
            <my-entry entry-data="entry"></my-entry>
        </div>
    </script>
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="entry.html">
        <div ng-if="entry.type === 'a'">{{entry.name}}</div>
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```